# JQuery3.0 throws error setting a property that has only a getter firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-3

I have created SVG circle dynamically and animated it small circle to large using JQuery. Animation was working fine in other JQuery version and throws exception **"setting a property that has only a getter"** in JQuery version 3.0 only. I have searched in online. It will caused due to the attribute don't have setter function.

```
_animateCircle: function (element, delayInterval) {
            var radius = element.getAttribute("r");
            var scaleVal;
            var $ele = $(element);
            var layer = this;
            $ele.delay(delayInterval).each(function () { }).animate(
                {   
                    r: radius // if i comment this line, exception not occur. But animation not working
                },
                {
                    duration: 700,

                    step: function (now) {
                        scaleVal = now;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

My question is why this not working only in JQuery version 3.0 only. Please advise me on this.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Answer (score 2):

Edit, Updated

Workaround for firefox where jQuery logs error at last `else` at `Tween.propHooks._default.set` line `6571`

```
else {
      tween.elem[ tween.prop ] = tween.now; // logs error
}
```

You can create an object having property of value equal to `r` value, which is an [`SVGAnimatedLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedLength) object, and property having value where animation should stop; at `step` function of `.animate()` called on the created object as parameter to `jQuery()` set property using `.attr("r", now)`, which appears to return same result at firefox, chromium

```js
var fx = {
  _animateCircle: function(element, delayInterval) {
    var r = element.attr("r");
    var radius = {from:r, to:r * 2}; // set `r` to `radius.to` value
    $(radius).delay(delayInterval).animate({
      from: radius.to
    }, {
      duration: 700,
      step: function(now) {
        element.attr("r", now);
      }
    });
  }
}

fx._animateCircle($("circle"), 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bxmgqnq3/3/

---

Substitute `$.fn.attr()` for `.getAttribute()`

```js
var fx = {
  _animateCircle: function(element, delayInterval) {
    var radius = element.attr("r") * 2;
    console.log(radius);
    var scaleVal;
    element.delay(delayInterval).animate({
      r: radius
    }, {
      duration: 700,
      step: function(now) {
        scaleVal = now;
      }
    });
  }
}

fx._animateCircle($("circle"), 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but still i am facing this issue in JQuery3.0

Comment: What is issue? Did you substitute `.attr()` for `.getAttribute()`?

Comment: No.. i am using .attr(). problem is not using .getAttribute(). If i use radius (  r: radius) in jquery animate method, that issue reproduced in Firefox only.