# JQuery-3.0 animate method with radius is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I am using latest JQuery version 3.0 animate method to animate SVG Circle element. This is working fine in JQuery-2.2.4. Firefox only have this console issue.

[JQuery-3.0 animation](https://jsfiddle.net/bxmgqnq3/1/)

```
  var fx = {
        _animateCircle: function (element, delayInterval) {
            var radius = element.attr("r");
            var box = $(element)[0].getBoundingClientRect(),
                 centerX = box.left + (box.width / 2),
        centerY = box.top + (box.height / 2);
            var scaleVal;
            element.delay(delayInterval).each(function () {  }).animate({
                r: radius
            }, {
                duration: 700,
                step: function (now) {
                    scaleVal = now;
                    $(element)[0].setAttribute("r", scaleVal);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    fx._animateCircle($("circle"), 500)
```

Any one advise me on this.

Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: WHat is the desired result supposed to be doing?

Comment: the circle will be animate small size to it's actual size. See in IE bowser

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code that states the animation should start from radius zero (or any other value), so it's animating from `r=50` to `r=50`, thus no animation is visible. The fact that it worked on previous versions of jQuery probably relied on buggy behaviour.

You can set the radius to zero after saving it to a variable:

```
var radius = element.attr("r");
element.attr("r", 0);
```

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/p9kbx0r5/

Comment: I got a solution from the blow post. Your solution still not resolve the issue in Firefox. Run your fiddle link in Firefox.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430148/jquery3-0-throws-error-setting-a-property-that-has-only-a-getter-firefox

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times, it wastes people's time and it is against the site rules.